# what is Oracle Managed Files?

Tags: database-design, oracle9i

1. What is the exact usage of OMF?
2. How init.ora files work?

Answer (score 1):

Has some examples here:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/OracleManagedFiles.php

Comment: Thanks a lot jxac but it will be great if you can give me some more detail regarding OMF.I also have some question regarding init.ora files.

Comment: The examples in the doc are not very clear to me...please help.